# Quantum mechanics: Finite square well problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential

What will happen if the potential is less than 0, for instance $V(x)=-10eV$. Is this means there will be no bound states? Since solution to the time independent Schrodinger equation (those discrete energies) must be greater than 0.

Comment: You are talking nonsense. There is always at least one bound state for the negative potential

Comment: Can you explain in more details? what is the difference between negative and positive potential? Sorry, I'm quite new to this area...

Comment: A negative potential is a potential $V(x)<V(\pm\infty)$ everywhere.

Comment: absolute potential is not defined, only **potential differences** are in play, as luming's comment makes explicit. plus for negative potential energy there are bound states.

Comment: Actually, we require that the energy eigenvalue be greater than the *minimum* of the potential energy (otherwise the solution is not normalizable).  In your example, the energy eigenstate will be a bound state if the associated energy eigenvalue is greater than -10eV and less than the potential energy at infinity.

Comment: "There is always at least one bound state for the negative potential in 1D", I should correct my statement, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/143630/why-the-statement-there-exist-at-least-one-bound-state-for-negative-potential

Answer (score 1):

Your finite square well potential looks like:

[image: Square well]

where $V_0$ is the potential energy outside the well and $V_1$ is the potential inside the well. The depth of the well is $\Delta V = V_0 - V_1$.

We normally take $V_0$ to be zero, in which case $V_1$ is negative (like your $-10$eV) and $\Delta V = V_1$. However you can add any constant value to the potential energies without changing the physics. That's because the wavefunction only depends on the well depth $\Delta V$, and adding the same constant term to $V_0$ and $V_1$ doesn't change $\Delta V$. We say the potential energy has a global gauge symmetry.

It's not clear from your question what you intended to have the value $-10$eV. You could set $V_0 = -10$eV and particles would still be bound in the well as long as $V_1$ was less than $-10$eV, that is $V_1 \lt V_0$.